# Displaying text on hover of image - getting string from rel attr

Tags: jquery

Not sure why this doesn't seem to work, I can do it by ID's with a hardcoded string for the description but when I try and do it more globally I can't get it to work right. Basically when you hover over an image, a p("desc") slides down and should display a text string in it.

HTML

```
<div id="awardCont" class="bottomBlock">
    <div id="award">
        <div class="trophy" rel="foo"></div>
        <div class="trophy"></div>
        <div class="trophy"></div>
        <p id="desc"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help.

The JS

```
$(function() {
        $('.trophy').hover(function() {
            var copy = $(this).attr(rel);
            $('#desc').slideDown('fast').html(copy);
        }, function() {
            $('#desc').slideUp('fast');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `rel` in quotes:

```
.attr('rel')
```

Comment: dammit. time to quit for the day I think. Thanks Leonard. Stupid question, appreciate the help.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :) Get some sleep ;)